# creating an array of link data and sending via JSON/AJAX

Tags: json, jquery

I am using jQuery and it's .map feature to create an array that I can send as a JSON string.

Whenever I try sending it, I get an error that states: ***e.text is not a function***.

Here is my HTML

```
 <a class="hrefURL" href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

and here is the jQuery

```
Links: $("[class=hrefURL]").map(function (i, e) {
         return { LinkURL: e.attr('href'), LinkText: e.text() };
         }).toArray()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried e.html()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the mapping function is a DOM element, not a jQuery object:

```
$('a[class="hrefURL"]').map(function (i, e) {
    var link = $(e);
    return { LinkURL: link.attr('href'), LinkText: link.text() };
}).toArray()
```

or to avoid the extra jQuery trip:

```
$('a[class="hrefURL"]').map(function (i, e) {
    return { LinkURL: e.href, LinkText: e.innerText };
}).toArray()
```

Comment: +1, Note however that using `.href` can have inconsistent results with relative urls in IE (such as `href="#somevalue"` becoming `href="http://foo.com/#somevalue"`).

Answer (score 2):

`e` is a dom element, not a jQuery object.

```
{ LinkURL: $(e).attr('href'), LinkText: $(e).text() };
```

though i'm not quite sure why it didn't first fail on `e.attr`